# using variable length argument in scala

Tags: scala

I know how to define a method with variable length argument:

```
  case class taxonomy(vocabularies:(String,Set[String])*)
```

and client code is very clean:

```
  val terms=taxonomy("topics"->Set("economic","politic")
                   ,"tag"->Set("Libya","evolution")
                   )
```

but I want to Know how can I use this case class when I have a variable (instead of a Sequence of variable) like this:

```
val notFormattedTerms = Map("topics"->Set("economic","politic")
       ,"tag"->Set("Libya","evolution"))
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
taxonomy(notFormattedTerms.toSeq:_*)
```

With `: _*` you virtually transform a sequence argument so that it looks as if a several arguments had been passed to the variable length method. This transformation, however, only works for (ordered?) simple sequence types and, as in this case, not for a `Map`. Therefore, one will have to use an explicit `toSeq` before.

Comment: I have yet to see why these conversions are not done implicitly (where applicable).

Comment: That would be rather confusing, I suppose.