# What is data type of the input of withFormUrlEncodedBody?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

```
def MakeRequest(method:String,url:String, data : Map[String,String]) = {
    route(FakeRequest(method,url).withHeaders("X-Requested-With" -> "1").withFormUrlEncodedBody(data)).get
  }
```

The error is at withFormUrlEncodedBody(data). It says that expected (String,String), actual: Map[String,String]. What exactly (String,String) data type?

I used `data:(String,String)` but the input only accepts 1 mapping. It would accept muptiple mappings. The following code is working without passing parameter:

```
route(FakeRequest(method,url).withHeaders("X-Requested-With" -> "1").withFormUrlEncodedBody("a" -> "b", "c" -> "d")).get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.test.FakeRequest), you will see that this is of type `(String, String)*`. First `(T1,T2)` stands for `Tuple2[T1,T2]`. Second, the `*` stands for a variable length argument, meaning that it accepts as many `Tuple2`'s that you want to send. This could be a `List` or another type of `Seq`

So, taking your original example, you could do the following:

```
def MakeRequest(method:String,url:String, data : (String,String)*) = {
    route(FakeRequest(method,url)
      .withHeaders("X-Requested-With" -> "1")
      .withFormUrlEncodedBody(data:_*)).get
  }
```

Comment: yes, that what I tried, but still received error: expected (String,String) actual: Seq[(String,String)]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to cast this. For more information about casting appropriately -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079845/using-variable-length-argument-in-scala