# How to convert an inmutable Seq of immutable Seq into a mutable Seq of mutable Seq in Scala?

Tags: scala, immutability, mutable

Let an immutable Seq of immutable Seqs be:

```
val content: Seq[Seq[Double]
```

that I'd like to transform as a mutable Seq of mutable Seqs:

```
val mutable_being_inversed_matrix:
  collection.mutable.Seq[collection.mutable.Seq[Double]] =
    content.to[collection.mutable.Seq[collection.mutable.Seq[Double]]
```

But this generates the following error:

```
Error:(79, 128)
  scala.collection.mutable.Seq[scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Double]]
    takes no type parameters, expected: one
  val mutable_being_inversed_matrix: collection.mutable.Seq[collection.mutable.Seq[Double]] = content.to[collection.mutable.Seq[collection.mutable.Seq[Double]]]
```

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this immutable input:

```
val immutableInput = Seq(Seq(1, 2), Seq(4))
```

you can switch to a mutable Seq of mutable Seqs by using the [varargs constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5079947/9297144):

```
scala.collection.mutable.Seq(
  immutableInput.map(imseq => scala.collection.mutable.Seq(imseq:_*)):_*
)
```

which produces:

```
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Int]] =
  ArrayBuffer(ArrayBuffer(1, 2), ArrayBuffer(4))
```